Azure keyvault issue - DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials
I am trying to access a SAS token which is stored on a Azure keyvault under secrets.
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

# Set up Key Vault client
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
key_vault_url = "https://abcdefghijklmnop.vault.azure.net/"
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=key_vault_url, credential=credential)

# Retrieve the secret
secret_name = "xxxxxxxxxx"
secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name).value
print(secret)

I am getting the below error, Am i doing this correctly?
EnvironmentCredential.get_token failed: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
ManagedIdentityCredential.get_token failed: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
SharedTokenCacheCredential.get_token failed: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
VisualStudioCodeCredential.get_token failed: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.
AzureCliCredential.get_token failed: Azure CLI not found on path
DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
    EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
    ManagedIdentityCredential: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable, no managed identity endpoint found.
    SharedTokenCacheCredential: SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
    VisualStudioCodeCredential: Failed to get Azure user details from Visual Studio Code.
    AzureCliCredential: Azure CLI not found on path
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientAuthenticationError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [13], line 11
      9 # Retrieve the secret
     10 secret_name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
---> 11 secret = secret_client.get_secret(secret_name).value
     12 secret


are you trying form your local machine? are you authenticated to azure ?

I am running from a Azure pipeline. have also tried on a Azure notebook in ML studio

can you share the relevant devops task? looks like you re not authenticated to azure?

Hi Thomas, it is a CICD pipeline for my machine learning model. Previusly I had hardcoded the SAS token into my code and now I am trying to fix the vulnerability. Hence I have stored in a scret of a keyvault. which I am trying to access

yeah but who / which service principal has access to this key vault? from the error message you re not authencated to azure in your devops pipeline

We have a Service Principal which has contributor access to the keyvault. The same service principal is also used in script. @Thomas - SHould i add/edit any permissions of this service principal on the keyvault and it's secrets?

yes the SP need list / read secret on the KV

The error means that Azure's DefaultCredential class fails to authenticate you or your app to Keyvault. As you can read in the traceback it tries several authentication methods.
How to authenticate? This depends if you try this on your local machine or in another app.
Locally for you personally as a user, you can for example install Azure CLI, and run az login to login to Azure. Like this, DefaultCredential can use AzureCliCredential. Another method is to run this:
credential = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_interactive_browser_credential=False)

Now, you tell DefaultCredential to add InteractiveBrowserCredential as an option, and a browser window will open where you can login with your personal account. Needless to say, this only works for personal usage, not for other apps.
In case of authentication for other applications you can for example use environment credentials. Create a secret in Azure in an App Reg which has access to keyvault. Then export AZURE_CLIENT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET and AZURE_TENANT_ID as environment variables. Now, DefaultCredential can use EnvironmentCredential for authentication.
This is the first step, authenticate to Azure. If DefaultCredential was able to authenticate you or your application, you can use credential in your SecretClient to retrieve any secret from the Keyvault you want.
See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-python
